# SObjectException “SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field” : Lead

Tags: apex, trigger, leads, before-trigger, after-trigger

I am writing a trigger to update Target Account Checkbox on Lead Object if any of the existing queue checkbox fields is true.

```
trigger TargetAccount on Lead (before insert,after insert,before update) {
    List<Lead> targ = [Select Id,Target_Account__c from Lead];
   
    for (Lead ld : targ){
        if(ld.Dylan_s_Target_Queue__c  == True ||ld.Buke_s_Target_Queue__c == True ||ld.Charlie_s_Target_Queue__c == True ||ld.Mark_s_Target_Queue__c == True ||ld.Matt_s_Target_Queue__c == True ||ld.Raza_s_Target_Queue__c == True ||ld.Caner_Target_Queues__c == True ||ld.Simon_s_Target_Queue__c == True){
          ld.Target_Account__c = True; 
          targ.add(ld);
        }
       update targ;
    }
}
```

I have some issues writing triggers for this functionality, so I end up getting this error, whenever I test creating a new lead.
Can someone help in fixing this issue

Comment: welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to visit the [help], scroll through the [tour], and read [ask]. What have you researched? Your specific error message is due to not specifying a field in your SOQL statement that you then try to reference. However, I'd recommend going through some trailheads on [triggers](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_triggers/apex_triggers_intro) as you shouldn't be querying for the records in your use case to begin with - see [execution context](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/apex_basics_dotnet/execution_context)

Comment: Likewise, [trigger context variables](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_context_variables.htm) will be of interest (see `Trigger.new`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are updating the same object (Lead) using the fields on the same object (Lead), you dont need `after` events, and you dont need to re-query for records. `Trigger.new` should have everything you need.

```
trigger TargetAccount on Lead (before insert, before update) {
    for (Lead ld : Trigger.new){
        if(ld.Dylan_s_Target_Queue__c  == true || ... ){
           ld.Target_Account__c = true; 
        } else {
           ld.Target_Account__c = false; 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you It worked!